# How to change default baud rate? From 115200 to 19200

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-hydro, rate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

How to change default baud rate? From 115200 to 19200

Instead USB-COM converter I have Arduino. I've checked it from Windows and Roomba was controlled by me.

SW:
Ubuntu Precise 12.04
ROS Hydro
ros-hydro-desktop-full
ros-hydro-turtlebot ros-hydro-turtlebot-apps ros-hydro-turtlebot-viz ros-hydro-turtlebot-simulator ros-hydro-kobuki-ftdi

HW:
Sony VAIO
iRobot Roomba 620
Arduino UNO

Regards,
Kirill Mitkovskii,

Thx!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/132076/how-to-change-default-baud-rate?-from-115200-to-19200/) by [Robotics010](https://answers.ros.org/users/12336/robotics010/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which node are you trying to use with your serial port?

The wiki page for the node you're using should describe how to set the baud rate.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0